# I would like to replace &#039; with ' in bash

Tags: string, bash, replace

I would like to simply replace `&#039;` with `'` but it does not work. The real problem is that  googling "&#039;" in combination with "bash" isn't really helpful.

Here is the simple script I was making.

```
#!/bin/bash

STR=$(curl http://www.billboard.com/charts/billboard-200)

I=0

while true; do 
    let "I += 1"
    #Find album
    STR=${STR#*Song Hover-}
    SONG=${STR%%div*}
    SONG=${SONG:0:${#SONG}-5}
    STR=${STR#*div}
    SONG = ${SONG/"&#039;"/"'"} #This line does not work
    echo ${SONG}
    SONGS[I]=${SONG}

    #find artist
    STR=${STR#*Artist Name}
    ARTIST=${STR%%a>*}
    ARTIST=${ARTIST:3:${#ARTIST}-6}
    STR=${STR#*a>}
    echo ${ARTIST}
    ARTISTS[I]=${ARTIST}


    TEST=${STR#*Song Hover-}
    if [ ${#TEST} -eq ${#STR} ]; then
        break;
    fi
done
```

Comment: Magic keywords: `bash` + `html` + `entities` + `decode`. Happy googling.

Comment: Good early S.O. question, except you should show us what you need for output, given you `STR=...` input. Good luck.

Comment: That said, I would also strongly suggest looking at tools like XMLStarlet to do proper XML parsing, rather than the string-munging approach here.

Comment: ...using a proper XML parser will *also* do entity decoding for you, making this problem entirely moot.

Comment: BTW, using all-caps names for your own variables is bad form; all caps names are reserved for variables impacting and provided by the system (`HOME`, `PATH`, `LANG`, etc) and the shell (`PS1`, `PWD`, etc), while names with at least one lower-case character are reserved for application use. See fourth paragraph of IEEE 1003.1 at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html, keeping in mind that shell variables and environment variables share a namespace.

Comment: Thx for all your advise!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whitespace messed you up:

```
SONG = ${SONG/"&#039;"/"'"}
```

needs to be...

```
SONG=${SONG/"&#039;"/"'"}
```

---

Having spaces around the `=` makes it not an assignment but a regular command, running a program named `SONG` with the first argument `=` and a second argument dependent on the actual song name.

Comment: Ow my god, it works. Actually I just tried double quotes and many other things, but double quotes and remove the spaces works. I thought it would be very complicated... Thx!